# Why is it not rendering as table html

Tags: html

I am trying to write a simple page with some tables in it..

I am wondering why it is not treating the element as table row and columns.. and just as normal text?

http://jsfiddle.net/zU2uD/

```
<table>
<!--{% for data in tabledata %}-->

<tr>
<td>{{ data[0]}}</td>
<td>{{ data[1]}}</td>
</tr>


<!--{% endfor %}-->
</table>
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _it is not treating the element as table row and columns.. and just as normal text_? What are you expecting?

Comment: @KevinBoucher: I am expecting the above to be displayed as :
[data[0]][data[1]]
i.e a table with 1 row and 2 columns?

Comment: What language or framework is `{{ data[0]}}`?

Comment: @j08691 It is coming from flask (python)

Comment: Looks like a table to me http://jsfiddle.net/zU2uD/

Comment: @Fraz It _IS_ a table with one row and two columns.

Comment: I checked the fiddle and it does seem to render in the html as a table, is your problem about how the table **looks**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add some CSS to [*style* the cells](http://jsfiddle.net/zU2uD/), you will see the table structure:

```
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I have added a visible border to the cells, so you can see the table structure.